# Strategy or Adapter pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns, adapter, strategy-pattern

I want to create some classes of each Virtual Server Provider, for example:

- Digital Ocean
- Linode
- Amazon AWS

Each Provider has own PHP class (via composer) to use their API interface, I want to use their class library but I want to make sure I can use same method for each provider. For example of shutting down VPS:

- Linode API method: `powerOff()`
- Digital Ocean API method: `haltServer()`

Rather than using `powerOff()` and `haltServer()` - I want to use `shutdown()` method for any providers classes I will create. Should I use Strategy design or Adaptor pattern?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Should I use Strategy design or Adaptor pattern?

This is the classic mistake everyone makes when designing an application (including myself). You should *ideally* not skim through the list of available design patterns and pick one that best matches your problem. Instead, you should come up with an initial class design and then try to identify the pattern that best describes your design. This safeguards you from *over-designing* i.e, creating unnecessary components which you don't otherwise require. With time, you soon have a vocabulary of design patterns that you have actually used rather than an application that tries to use a particular design pattern.

Leaving design patterns aside, it looks like what you are searching for is a way to provide a common interface for performing the same functionality using different underlying libraries/approaches. This sounds a lot like *Abstraction* and *Delegation*.

You can achieve *Abstraction* by defining a common interface called *Provider* with the standard operation methods such as `shutdown`, `connect`, `retry`, etc. You can then create one concrete provider class for each type of provider such as `AWSProvider` and `LinodeProvider` and implement the `shutdown`, `connect` and `retry` methods. You then use *Delegation* by calling the provider specific APIs within these methods. For example, call the `powerOff` method inside `shutdown` method of `LinodeProvider` class.

If you now take a good look at your design, you will start to realize that it looks like the *Strategy* as well as the *Aadpter* pattern. What distinguishes the two patterns is the point of time where the *Abstraction* comes into play. If you decide the *Provider* implementation to be used via a *Factory* at runtime of the application, you are using the *Strategy* pattern; however, if this decision is made at compile time, you are using the *Adapter* pattern. Other than the name of the pattern, your classes will pretty much look the same.

The advantage of this approach is that you have not only identified the right pattern, but you have also safeguarded yourself from over-designing the application by using patterns such as the *Command* pattern.

Comment: Amen. While one should be aware of patterns, they should not drive design decisions so much as emerge as the design takes shape.

Comment: "What distinguishes the two patterns is the point of time where the Abstraction comes into play" - Where did you get that from? "ideally not skim through the list of available design patterns and pick one that best matches your problem" - That makes no sense at all, patterns are there to solve common problems in a proven way.

Comment: @plalx Thanks for the comment. 1. The Adapter pattern comes into play when you need to adapt an existing implementation/library to your codebase. This is something that cannot be done without writing and compiling new components/code. The goal of the Strategy pattern on the other hand is to allow you to choose the appropriate implementation (usually at runtime) without a lot of compile time changes (read factory). Thus, the point in time governs their name. 2. You don't have to agree but read [this](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141854/design-patterns-do-you-use-them)

Comment: @CKing Thanks for detailed answer, much appreciated. I have just done a quick pseudo do you can suggestion me what kind of pattern would be suited: http://pastebin.com/yYkwPpAG

Comment: @U'll-Be-Back I am not a php programmer but what is the purpose of the `shutdown` and `powerOn` classes?. That code should ideally be placed inside the provider implementations directly IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question: [Adapter](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Adapter/),
[Strategy](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Strategy/) is used when you can have one or more implemenations of the algortihm.

p.s. suggestion with [Command](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Command/) pattern is OK as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I have just done a quick pseudo code so you can suggestion me what kind of pattern would be suited for that kind of logic. http://pastebin.com/yYkwPpAG

Comment: well I am not expert in PHP but check this example, https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter/php, class BookAdpater is place where adaptation is implemeted

Answer (score 0):

The best fitting design pattern here is neither `Strategy` nor `Adaptor`.
In my view you should check [Command pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command).

This pattern solves the exact same problem you are asking. It'll provide a single method as you asked in your case `shutdown` and through dependence it can call any method exposed by the dependency.

Comment: Even though suggest that the OP uses the `Command` pattern, your justification sounds more like the `Strategy` pattern. One of the components of the command pattern is an `Invoker`. Can you specify what would the `Invoker` be in this particular case?